# MonoMac: Error in file jit.h: 'mono/metadata/appdomain.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, macos, mono

I added Mono in my project as link binary Mono.framework.

But when I try include class of Mono framework I get error: 'mono/metadata/appdomain.h' file not found

```
#import <Mono/mono-2.0/mono/jit/jit.h>
```

But in headers appdomain.h exist.

I use OS X 10.7.3, XCode 4.3.1, Mono 2.10.8.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Mono Framework MDK (you likely installed the runtime-only).

Comment: No. I installed MDK and MRE. :(

Comment: MDK and MRE are the same thing, except the MDK has the development header files. If you installed the MRE overtop of the MDK, then it will have removed the headers.